# Dockerfile COPY with wildcard failing in the GitLab pipeline. "no source files were specified"

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gitlab-ci

Below Dockerfile builds perfectly locally but fails in the GitLab pipeline.

The result on my local machine and in the GitLab pipeline. Look that in the pipeline we can see the result of the ls command that proves that the files actually exists.

This copy command:

`COPY --from=TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE $APP_HOME/build/libs/$ARTIFACT_NAME` .

Fails with:

> COPY failed: no source files were specified.

Dockerfile

```
FROM gradle:7.2-jdk11 AS TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE

ENV APP_HOME=/usr/api/
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY build.gradle settings.gradle gradle.properties $APP_HOME

COPY gradle $APP_HOME/gradle
COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/src
USER root
RUN chown -R gradle /home/gradle/src

RUN gradle build || return 0
COPY . .
RUN gradle clean build
RUN ls $APP_HOME/build/libs/

# actual container
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk13-openj9:jdk-13.0.2_8_openj9-0.18.0-alpine-slim
ENV ARTIFACT_NAME=strangler-*-all.jar
ENV APP_HOME=/usr/api/

WORKDIR $APP_HOME
RUN echo ECHO
RUN echo $APP_HOME/build/libs/$ARTIFACT_NAME
COPY --from=TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE $APP_HOME/build/libs/$ARTIFACT_NAME . <--------------------- FAILS HERE!!!

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT exec java -jar ${ARTIFACT_NAME}
```

Result on local machine

```
bruno.carneiro@Brunos-MacBook-Pro strangler % docker build . -t test-dockerfile
[+] Building 128.0s (21/21) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 759B                                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/adoptopenjdk/openjdk13-openj9:jdk-13.0.2_8_openj9-0.18.0-alpine-slim                                                                                                                                        0.7s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/gradle:7.2-jdk11                                                                                                                                                                                    1.7s
 => [stage-1 1/5] FROM docker.io/adoptopenjdk/openjdk13-openj9:jdk-13.0.2_8_openj9-0.18.0-alpine-slim@sha256:1618df660be143417bdf9badbda5c022cccfe37829e4967d8edb07c4042837d3                                                                          0.0s
 => [temp_build_image  1/10] FROM docker.io/library/gradle:7.2-jdk11@sha256:64a869d95a258a0a179763a320f3ffb85382214d04a9407afb1a4e485fcc00a8                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.1s
 => => transferring context: 36.48kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.1s
 => CACHED [temp_build_image  2/10] WORKDIR /usr/api/                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [temp_build_image  3/10] COPY build.gradle settings.gradle gradle.properties /usr/api/                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [temp_build_image  4/10] COPY gradle /usr/api//gradle                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [temp_build_image  5/10] COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/src                                                                                                                                                                             0.1s
 => [temp_build_image  6/10] RUN chown -R gradle /home/gradle/src                                                                                                                                                                                      0.5s
 => [temp_build_image  7/10] RUN gradle build || return 0                                                                                                                                                                                             76.3s
 => [temp_build_image  8/10] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.1s
 => [temp_build_image  9/10] RUN gradle clean build                                                                                                                                                                                                   47.5s
 => [temp_build_image 10/10] RUN ls /usr/api//build/libs/                                                                                                                                                                                              0.5s
 => CACHED [stage-1 2/5] WORKDIR /usr/api/                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1 3/5] RUN echo ECHO                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1 4/5] RUN echo /usr/api//build/libs/strangler-*-all.jar                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [stage-1 5/5] COPY --from=TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE /usr/api//build/libs/strangler-*-all.jar .                                                                                                                                                              0.1s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.2s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.2s
 => => writing image sha256:b6752359ac3fc50b20f275270442cd93fc27fb285c5e50430cc15ca6596c5d1d                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/test-dockerfile
```

Result on GitLab pipeline

```
[ ... ]

Step 12/21 : RUN ls $APP_HOME/build/libs/ <----------------- PROVES THE FILES EXIST
 ---> Running in 49ae17677df 
strangler-0.1-all.jar
strangler-0.1.jar
strangler-0.1-runner.jar
Removing intermediate container 49ae17677dfa
 ---> 49fa966bdc46
Step 13/21 : FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk13-openj9:jdk-13.0.2_8_openj9-0.18.0-alpine-slim
jdk-13.0.2_8_openj9-0.18.0-alpine-slim: Pulling from adoptopenjdk/openjdk13-openj9
df20fa9351a1: Already exists
f1a790472f05: Already exists
449b3bf6a04e: Already exists
6d408a52a4b1: Already exists
Digest: sha256:1618df660be143417bdf9badbda5c022cccfe37829e4967d8edb07c4042837d3
Status: Downloaded newer image for adoptopenjdk/openjdk13-openj9:jdk-13.0.2_8_openj9-0.18.0-alpine-slim
 ---> 2b34114f0c98
Step 14/21 : ENV ARTIFACT_NAME=strangler-*-all.jar
 ---> Running in 393a0a6c1938
Removing intermediate container 393a0a6c1938
 ---> 3190a502ec30
Step 15/21 : ENV APP_HOME=/usr/api/
 ---> Running in abb26ef55c62
Removing intermediate container abb26ef55c62
 ---> 0e2eb6606643
Step 16/21 : WORKDIR $APP_HOME
 ---> Running in 0d6addbc0dc9
Removing intermediate container 0d6addbc0dc9
 ---> 1568234714b2
Step 17/21 : RUN echo ECHO
 ---> Running in c14f6b19e842
ECHO
Removing intermediate container c14f6b19e842
 ---> 25ebe041c45c
Step 18/21 : RUN echo $APP_HOME/build/libs/$ARTIFACT_NAME
 ---> Running in b48bbd257c92
/usr/api//build/libs/strangler-*-all.jar
Removing intermediate container b48bbd257c92
 ---> 9a33bb9fd38b
Step 19/21 : COPY --from=TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE $APP_HOME/build/libs/$ARTIFACT_NAME .
COPY failed: no source files were specified. <---------- CANT FIND FILES
Cleaning up file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

Comment: I'd guess there are order-of-expansion differences between the BuildKit pipeline and the older pipeline.  Does using an older version of Docker, or setting an environment variable `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0`, reproduce the problem locally?

Comment: (I probably would not use environment variables for fixed path names in your image.  `COPY --from=TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE /usr/api/build/libs/*-all.jar api.jar` would avoid the order-of-expansion issue and give you a fixed name for the jar file in the final image.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I tried to set an env var adding the line ```ENV DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0``` in my Dockerfile but the error was not reproduced locally.

Comment: @DavidMaze When I removed the use of env var in the fixed path name the job passed in the pipeline. But I do not understood how you reached this conclusion. Could you give me some link to understand that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two versions of the `docker build` engine.  The "classic" builder outputs the `Step 13/21` lines; the newer [BuildKit engine](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/) writes out the `=> [stage-1 5/5]` lines.  Newer versions of Docker use BuildKit by default, but you can explicitly request it (or not) using the `DOCKER_BUILDKIT` environment variable (from the host when you run `docker build`, not within your Dockerfile).

Within your Dockerfile, you're in effect asking the build engine to do two different kinds of processing on the same line: replacing an environment variable reference with its value, and matching filenames against a shell glob.

```sh
ENV ARTIFACT_NAME=stranger-*-all.jar
COPY --from=TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE $APP_HOME/build/libs/$ARTIFACT_NAME .
```

If Docker *first* replaces the environment variable with its string representation, and *second* does the glob expansion, then this works as you expect.  But if it does glob expansion first and environment variable replacement second then it won't.  The behavior you're seeing is apparently that the two Docker build engines do this in opposite order.

(The Dockerfile documentation for [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) is silent on this point.  The [Environment replacement](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement) section suggests that environment variables should be replaced first.  If this were a shell, the [POSIX shell specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06) indicates parameter [environment variable] substitution would happen before pathname expansion.)

In practice, once you build a Dockerfile into an image, the path names are fixed.  It's not usually beneficial to set environment variables to represent path names unless the application specifically requires it.  For example, the `$APP_HOME` environment variable isn't used at all in your setup, except that it's the current working directory and a path in a different image.

The problematic `$ARTIFACT_NAME` apparently appears in two places.  You can fix the file name in the final image, though.  If you do that it only appears in the `COPY` statement, and again, you don't need a variable for it.

That would make the final Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM gradle:7.2-jdk11 AS TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE
...

FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk13-openj9:jdk-13.0.2_8_openj9-0.18.0-alpine-slim
WORKDIR /usr/api
COPY --from=TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE /usr/api/build/libs/stranger-*-all.jar stranger.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java", "-jar", "stranger.jar"]
```